# Ampersand state - how to observe State prop changes from an external State?

Tags: ampersand.js

Assuming that view bindings have to observe model props how can I trigger State change from State change in another State? might the the 2nd State be a derived prop or a child prop for example?

Comment: A simple way is to `listenTo` your model https://ampersandjs.com/docs/#ampersand-events-listento. You can also define your first State in the props, and make the second derived (if you want). Then during initialization you'd just pass in the first state to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, Ampersand-view bindings must observe current model (ampersand-state).

In order for current State to "listen" to another State, you can include the 2nd State as a prop of the current State using data-type "state", for example:

```
import State from 'ampersand-state';

export default State.extend({
    __name: 'ConnectionState',
    idAttribute: 'site_id',
    props: {
        site_id: ['any', true],
        message_group_id: ['any', true],
        message_group: ['state'],
```

Then when you initialize states, set the state prop with 2nd State:

```
let messageGroups = new MessageGroupsCollection(state.messageGroups);
let connections = new ConnectionsCollection(state.connections);

connections.forEach((model) => {
    model.set('message_group', messages.get(model.get('message_group_id')));
});
```

Now in your view (backed by State) you can bind to the other State like:

```
bindings: {
    'model.message_group.is_hired': {
        hook: 'isHired',
        type: 'toggle'
    }
},
```

Now when you make changes to message_group.is_hired, it will reflect in Connection bindings.